# Suppose $z,w\in\Bbb C$. Prove that if $\Re(z\bar w)=1$, then $|z+w|^4=|z|^4+|w|^4+2|z|^2|w|^2+4|z|^2+4|w|^2+4$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Suppose $z,w\in\Bbb C$. Prove that if $\Re(z\bar w)=1$, then $$|z+w|^4=|z|^4+|w|^4+2|z|^2|w|^2+4|z|^2+4|w|^2+4.$$

Let $z=a+bi$,   $w=x+yi$   and  I find $ax+by=1$.
But I don't know know to factorize $|z+w|^4$. Should I combine $z$ and $w$ or change them into $(a+bi)$ and $(x+yi)$?

[Picture of the problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSOk9.png)

Comment: the picture is in the link

Comment: I would perhaps start with combining $z$ and $w$. If an argument about complex numbers can be made without decomposing them into real and imaginary parts, then it will look a lot nicer. Also note that $|z+w|^4=(z+w)^2(\overline{z+w})^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Use the fact that 
$$|z+w|^2=(z+w)\overline{(z +w)}=(z+w){(\bar z +\bar w)}=|z|^2+|w|^2+ z\bar w +\bar z w \\=|z|^2+|w|^2+ 2\mbox{Re}(z\bar w)=
|z|^2+|w|^2+ 2.$$

P.S. Note that $\overline{z\bar w}=\bar z w$, so if $z\bar w=x+iy$ then
$$z\bar w +\bar z w=(x+iy)+(x-iy)=2x=2\mbox{Re}(z\bar w).$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use the fact that $|z+w|^2=(z+w)\overline{(z+w)}$.